# python variable in __init__.py cannot be accessed. module not found

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to make python flask server. I made db and app variable inside **init**.py file and try to call in inside app.py and player.py. However, when I run app.py it says that `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'server'` in `from server import app` in app.py.

Also, when run a command `flask run`, I got an error saying `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'config'`. I'm not quite sure why it's saying no module found even though variables present inside **init**.py.

can anyone help me how to fix this issue?

The structure is

```
Backend
      └──server
            ├── models
                  └── player.py
            ├── __init__.py
            ├── config.py
            └── app.py
```

**init**.py is

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy  
from flask_cors import CORS
import os

template_dir = os.path.abspath('static')
app = Flask(__name__,template_folder=template_dir)
app.config.from_object('config.Config')
CORS(app)

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

from .models import player

import server.app
```

app.py is

```
from flask import Flask,render_template, request, make_response,jsonify
import os
from server import app
from models.player import Player


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    print('hello')
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

config.py is

```
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv

class DevConfig:
    load_dotenv()
    # SQLAlchemy
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{dbname}?charset=utf8'.format(**{
        'user': os.getenv('DB_USER', 'root'),
        'password': os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'host': os.getenv('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'dbname': os.getenv('DB_NAME')
    })
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = True
    SQLALCHEMY_ECHO = False


Config = DevConfig
```

and player.py is

```
from server import db
from datetime import datetime


class Player(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'player'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)  # player id
    password = db.Column(db.String(255))  # password
```

Comment: `Backend` needs to be in your module search path. You might try something like `PTYHONPATH=/path/to/Backend flask run`, but it's usually easier to just ensure that `server` gets installed in a virtual environment before executing your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `__init__.py`, change last line to:

```py
from server import app
```

Remove the last two lines from `app.py` and create a new file called `run.py` in the parent directory (Backend). `run.py` should contain:

```py
from server import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='localhost', port=5000)
```

I think Flask's naming conventions are a little confusing sometimes. If you call the `app.py` file something else (I usually call mine "routes.py"), then things become a little more clear, e.g.

`routes.py`

```py
from flask import Flask,render_template
from server import app

@app.get('/')
def index():
    print('hello')
    return render_template('index.html')
```

`__init__.py`

```py
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from server import routes
```

`../run.py`

```py
from server import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Comment: thank you! I made run.py in Backend and move .env and config.py to Backend (since I got module not found error when they were in server folder). then it's working!